# Probability density function for intervals in R

Tags: r

I need function that returns probability densities of exponential distribution for given intervals (`breaks`).

How I did it:

```
breaks <- c(0, 0.2, 0.5, Inf)

p1 <- pexp(.2) ## [0, 0.2]
p2 <- pexp(.5) - pexp(.2) ## (0.2, 0.5]
p3 <- 1 - pexp(.5) ## (.5, Inf)
```

How I want it to be done:

```
>> pdf_exp(breaks = breaks)
  [0,0.2] (0.2,0.5] (0.5,Inf] 
0.1812692 0.2122001 0.6065307
```

Comment: I need that probabilities for Pearson's chi-squared test. In this formula it's $P_{i}$: $X_{n}^{2}=n\sum _{i=1}^{k}{\frac {\left(n_{i}/n-P_{i}(\theta )\right)^{2}}{P_{i}(\theta )}}$

Comment: @user20650, yep you are right, I am mistaking with that part, just confused by the concept of probablity densities given by OP. Then It's just total probability over an interval, not probability density which is calculated by `dexp`.

Comment: `diff(pexp(breaks))` gives `[1] 0.1812692 0.2122001 0.6065307`.

Comment: Thank you. `R` is great.